# Fast sort dataTable

Tags: c#, .net

Is possible to do fast sort data in DataTable ?

I have a dataTable with a some rows (30k ~ 500k). I must sort in dataTable (not dataView etc). I have query with sory parameters so i use

```
var view = dataTable.DefaultView;
view.Sort = sortParameters;

var dataTable = view.ToTable();
```

This part is ok, and does very fast, but is one warning. If i use view.ToTable(), the new table doesn't have setted primaryKey. I must set that again, and this operation cost a lot of time :/

I can't change this. I must join two dataTables (with the same table definition but from other source) and return one with setted primaryKeys - how i say before i can't skip that.

Is any way to speed up this ?

Comment: Where will you use your sorted table?

Answer (score 2):

Use LINQ if you can. It's the fastest way I've found. You'll need to reference DataSetExtensions, in .net 3.5. You'll end up with an IEnumerable instead of a table, however.

```
var drs = from x in dataTable.Rows
          where x.Field<someFieldType>("FieldName") == etc
          orderby x.Field<someFieldType1>('SortFieldName')
          select x;
```

Remove the `where` clause to sort only. Replace `someFieldType` and `sortFieldName` with your own values respectively.

on drs you can do .ToArray(), or import it to a DataTable, etc.

Comment: + you can use `.AsParallel()` in linq to do faster the sort!

Comment: Yeah, my main project at work isn't up to .NET 4 yet, so I haven't been able to make use of PLINQ yet.